# Snowflake external tables not visible in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a set of External Tables in Snowflake, which reference data stored in AWS S3.

When users try and create a model in Power BI using these tables they are unable to see any of the External Tables in the object tree of the "Navigator" dialog. If a schema contains only external tables, then the schema itself is also not shown. Normal tables and views are shown as expected.

It's not a permissions issue as users are able to run queries against the external tables, they're just not able to select them from the object tree when creating a data model.

Other tools that connect to Snowflake display external tables as if they were normal tables.

Is this an issue with Power BI? I haven't been able to find any other references to this issue but surely we can't be the only people using Power BI with Snowflake external tables.

Comment: It's possible that PowerBI just isn't listing them from the Snowflake catalog.  One possible reason is that External Tables are currently in Preview, but I'm not really sure.  As you said, Snowflake presents External Tables in the catalog as being tables, so no reason why a tool can't display them.

Comment: external tables is still quite new. It depends on how PowerBI "discovers" schemas. If they use "show tables" they should be fine. If they use something else, it might not work.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend contacting Microsoft as this would depend on the API call being made from PowerBI via the driver.   As you mentioned, other tools support this (so it's not a driver or Snowflake limitation), so Microsoft would need PowerBI to support finding external tables as well in their calls.